# Making a Snake with Java Applet

Tags: java, graphics, processing

so I'm trying to reproduce this graphics program [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=6nODeX5yBqU) for my java class.

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Assignment09b extends PApplet {

// Create arrays to stort the x & y values of the mouse
int [] xArray = new int [100];
int [] yArray = new int [100];

public void setup(){
    //Runs at 60Fps

    size(500, 500);
}

public void draw(){
    //Changes the background each frame
    background(0);

    //Stores the x&y values of the mouse in the arrays
    for (int i = 0; i < xArray.length; i++){
        xArray[i] = this.mouseX;
        yArray[i] = this.mouseY;
    }

    //SHOULD print out the snake using series of ellipses
    for (int i = 0; i < xArray.length; i++){

        //Generates a random color each time
        fill(random(255), random(255), random(255));
        ellipse(xArray[i], yArray[i], 25, 25);
    }

}
   }
```

I have a few ideas as to what the problem might be:

1. Because I'm in a loop, its just spawning one ellipse really quickly but I don't know how to have it spawn them simultaneously
2. It might be an issue with the frame rate speed maybe?
3. I'm an incompetent programmer :/

Please guys can you please give me some advice as to what I may be doing wrong or not at all. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're setting all the values at the same time here:

```
//Stores the x&y values of the mouse in the arrays
    for (int i = 0; i < xArray.length; i++){
        xArray[i] = this.mouseX;
        yArray[i] = this.mouseY;
    }
```

You only want to update 1 element in the array and have the others shift by one: the 'oldest' value goes out, the new value comes in. You can manually use a reverse for loop (from the end of the array to the front excepting the 1st element) or use [arrayCopy](http://processing.org/reference/arrayCopy_.html):

```
private void updateArrays(int x,int y){
  arrayCopy(xArray, 0, xArray, 1, xArray.length-1);//shift all elements backwards by 1
  arrayCopy(yArray, 0, yArray, 1, yArray.length-1);//so x at index 99 goes 98, 98 to 97, etc. excepting index 0
  xArray[0] = x;//finally add the newest value 
  yArray[0] = y;//at the start of the array (so in the next loop it gets shifted over by 1) like the above values
}
```

which makes the full listing:

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Assignment09b extends PApplet {
  // Create arrays to stort the x & y values of the mouse
  int [] xArray = new int [100];
  int [] yArray = new int [100];

  public void setup(){
      //Runs at 60Fps

      size(500, 500);
  }

  public void draw(){
      //Changes the background each frame
      background(0);

      updateArrays(mouseX,mouseY);

      //SHOULD print out the snake using series of ellipses
      for (int i = 0; i < xArray.length; i++){

          //Generates a random color each time
          fill(random(255), random(255), random(255));
          ellipse(xArray[i], yArray[i], 25, 25);
      }

  }

  private void updateArrays(int x,int y){
    arrayCopy(xArray, 0, xArray, 1, xArray.length-1);//shift all elements backwards by 1
    arrayCopy(yArray, 0, yArray, 1, yArray.length-1);//so x at index 99 goes 98, 98 to 97, etc. excepting index 0
    xArray[0] = x;//finally add the newest value 
    yArray[0] = y;//at the start of the array (so in the next loop it gets shifted over by 1) like the above values
  }
}
```

Since this is an exercise I recommend playing with for loops and arrays more. 
It's something you'll end up using quite a lot and worth practicing/getting the hang of.
Goodluck!

```js
var xArray = new Array(100);
var yArray = new Array(100);

function setup(){
  createCanvas(500, 500);
}

function draw(){
    //Changes the background each frame
    background(0);

    updateArrays(mouseX,mouseY);

    //SHOULD print out the snake using series of ellipses
    for (var i = 0; i < xArray.length; i++){

        //Generates a random color each time
        fill(random(255), random(255), random(255));
        ellipse(xArray[i], yArray[i], 25, 25);
    }

}

function updateArrays(x,y){
  arrayCopy(xArray, 0, xArray, 1, xArray.length-1);//shift all elements backwards by 1
  arrayCopy(yArray, 0, yArray, 1, yArray.length-1);//so x at index 99 goes 98, 98 to 97, etc. excepting index 0
  xArray[0] = x;//finally add the newest value 
  yArray[0] = y;//at the start of the array (so in the next loop it gets shifted over by 1) like the above values
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.4.4/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And yes I definitely need to explore arrays and for loops in more depth.